# Menus at the bottom of the app shows twice

Tags: android, menu

I create the menu file containing three items. Menus in action bar shows only three items but on mobile menu button (hardware button)on same page  show same item twice. I used menu.clear() but it not worked. Please suggest me if any solution. I attached the code with the questions.please reply me.  Thank you in advance.

```
                @Override
                public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
                {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.ticket_webview);

                Intent intent = getIntent(); // get data from previous activity 
                Ticket_hash=intent.getStringExtra("Ticket_hash");
                Ticket_title=intent.getStringExtra("title");
                ID=intent.getStringExtra("ID");
                filter_id=intent.getStringExtra("filter_id");


                is_queue_set=intent.getStringExtra("set_queue");
                if(is_queue_set!="Null" || is_queue_set!="")
                {
                SET_QUEUE=is_queue_set; 
                }
                else
                {
                SET_QUEUE="";   
                }


                webview =(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);   
                webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
                //webview.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);//THIS ONE COMMENTED Instead of the setPluginsEnabled there will be new method setPluginState,
                //setPluginsEnabled is removed in the api level 18
                webview.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
                new ticketPost().execute(); // parse data from json file using Asynctask

                }
```

//********

```
                @Override
                public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                menu.clear();//To eleminate duplicate menubar at the bottom 
                MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
                menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.ticket_properties_menu, menu);
                return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
                }
```

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

```
                switch (item.getItemId())
                {

                case R.id.menu_add_note:

                Intent i3 = new Intent(Ticket_posts.this,Add_note.class);

                startActivity(i3);
                return true;

                case R.id.menu_send_reply:

                Intent reply= new Intent(Ticket_posts.this,Send_reply.class);

                startActivity(reply);
                return true;

                case R.id.menu_pin:


                return true;

                default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
                }
                }
```

//Ticket_properties_menu.xml

```
 <item android:id="@+id/menu_pin"
      android:icon="@drawable/pin"
      android:title="@string/pin"
     android:showAsAction="never" 
      />

<item android:id="@+id/menu_send_reply"
      android:icon="@drawable/send"
      android:title="@string/send_reply"
      android:showAsAction="never" 
      />

<item android:id="@+id/menu_add_note"
      android:icon="@drawable/add_note"
      android:title="@string/add_note"
      android:showAsAction="never" 
       />
```

Comment: Can you show us the xml for `ticket_properties_menu`?

Comment: @Vucko : I update the question.